# Imprimir sempre que variável receber certo valor

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo simples no qual sempre que um objeto sair da tela uma variável de nome score recebe +1.

A ideia é simples, o que estou tentando fazer é com que seja imprimido o valor da variável score sempre que o jogador fizer 10 novos pontos, ou seja, sempre que a variável score receber o valor dela mesma +10 é imprimido o valor da variável.

Para fazer isto eu declarei uma variável chamada x que recebe o mesmo valor de score, se x for igual a 10 é imprimido o valor de score. Assim que for imprimido o valor de score, x volta ao valor 0, e a ideia é repetir isto sem parar.

O problema é que depois de imprimir score e a variável x ser zerada, x volta a receber o valor de score e não será mais imprimido nada na tela, isto pois x não estará recebendo 0 de fato.

Como posso corrigir isto? Espero ter sido claro!

**CÓDIGO**

**Objeto:**

```
public int x;

void Start() {

}

void Update() {

}

void OnBecameInvisible() {
    Score.score += 1;
    x = Score.score;

    if (x == 10)
    {
        Debug.Log("VALOR DE SCORE: " + Score.score);
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

**Score:**

```
public static int score;
public Text score_txt;

void Start() {
    score = 0;
}

void Update () {
    score_txt.text = score.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa da variável `x`, apenas precisa validar se o resto da divisão inteira por **10** é **0**:

```
void OnBecameInvisible() 
{
    Score.score += 1;

    if ((Score.score % 10) == 0)
        Debug.Log("VALOR DE SCORE: " + Score.score);
}
```